# Installing cocos2d-x on windows 7

Tags: python, numpy, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, pywin

I'm trying to install cocos2d-x on win7. I've been following this guide http://cocos2d.org/doc/programming_guide/id1.html
I have python 2.5, pygame1.9.2, pyglet1.1.4, pywin, Cygwin and Mingw installed. The guide says that for cocos particles to work I need the python package Numpy. Then I found "numpy-1.7.0-win32-superpack-python2.5.exe" and installed. Yet, I still got this error when trying to run a basic helloworld script on pywin

```
ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: wrong type
```

it says Exception raised when running script.
What should I do now? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Compatibility notes at the time of writing, August 2011

NumPy 1.7.0 was released 2013-02-11 so you probably need the 1.6 version. Install 1.6.2 and try with that.